# AVPlayer does not update currentPlaybackTime when seeking backwards

Tags: ios, video-streaming, nstimer, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayer

I have an `NSTimer` set up that fires every `0.1` seconds, in the callback I fetch `currentTime()` and use it to update the label with the duration of the video.

When I am seeking forwards, by setting the `rate` to 3, this timer keeps up, but when I set the rate to -3, the video keeps up, but the `currentTime()` still returns the same value from when I started seeking. This occurs until I stop seeking and then `currentTime()` returns the correct time

How can I fetch the current time the video is at, which will work when seeking backwards?

**Edit:** Here is the code I use (translated from Xamarin C#):

```
class VideoPlayer: UIView {

    var player: AVPlayer!
    var wasPaused: Bool!

    func play(url: String) {
        // set the URL to the Video Player
        let streamingURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
        player = AVPlayer(URL: streamingURL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(layer: player)
        layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer, atIndex: 0)

        // Reset the state
        player.seekToTime(CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 600))

        // Start a timer to move the scrub label
        NSTimer(timeInterval: 0.1, target: self, selector: #selector(playbackTimeUpdated), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    func playbackTimeUpdated() {
        // This one is not correct when seeking backwards
        let time = player.currentTime().seconds;

        // Use the time to adjust a UIProgressView
    }

    // Gets called when the reverse button is released
    func reverseTouchUp() {
        player.rate = 1
    }

    // Gets called when the reverse button is pressed
    func reverseTouchDown()
    {
        player.rate = -3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add code? Just had tried this behavior on [demo project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVPlayerDemo/Introduction/Intro.html), works as expected.

Comment: @RomanErmolov I added my code, I will look into your code to try and see what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `CMTimeGetSeconds(player.currentTime())` instead of `player.currentTime().seconds`. It works for me.

Also check that you timer is actually running (add NSLog calls to it for example), maybe you just blocking its thread.

Comment: I wasn't blocking it's thread, but I noticed I had a check if the video was paused (obviously the movie time shouldn't update then), but I had it like this: `time > 0` instead of `time != 0`.

Comment: @vrwim in the above code, maybe everything is correct, and your `time>0` was the problem. now is it solved?